# Convergence of $L^1$ norms of a sequence in $L^\infty$ convergent in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I am dealing with a sequence $(u_n) \in L^2(D)$ where $D\subset \mathbb R^N$ is bounded, such that $0 \le u_n \le 1$. I know $u_n \to u$ in $L^2(D)$ and I would like to know whether or not

$$  \|u_n\|_1 \to \|u\|_1$$

Thank you ever so much.

Comment: By Hölder, $\int_D|u_n-u|\le\Bigl(\int |u_n-u|^2\Bigr)^{1/2}\Bigl(\int 1^2\Bigr)^{1/2}$. Note the hypothesis that $0\le u_n\le1$ is not needed (only the boundedness of $D$ is needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the triangle inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have $$\left|\|u_n\|_1 - \|u\|_1\right| \leq \|u_n - u\|_1 \leq \sqrt{\lambda(D)}\,\|u_n-u\|_2  \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$$
where $\lambda(D) < \infty$ is the Lebesgue measure of $D$.